# Creating WebService test harness

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to create a test harness for our QA staff to test our 
internal web services. I would like to create a web app that will 
allow them to enter a uri then submit. The web app will then 
interrogate the uri to get the appropriate parameters expected and 
returns with a generated input form. I know, this would be similar to 
SOAPUI and others. However, I feel it would be earier for them to be 
able to just use a form with entry fields and click a button to invoke 
the service and get the results back for display in the web app. In 
addition, I could create some custom logic that allows them to 
generate specific behavior they need.

Has anybody done anything like this? I have searched and have found 
similar functionality but nothing close enough to help me. If you need 
more details please let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned SOAPUI, but do you know that SOAPUI Pro has what you are asking for? An Automatic form editor from the WSDL - see the SOAPUI link [here](http://www.soapui.org/userguide/formeditor.html) for screenshot. 
You can get a two week trial for free and it's about $350 for a license, which is almost certainly cheaper than building it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that is a great option and I will probably consider it if I cannot find a way to do this myself. This is as much a training exercise as a tool for QA. Also, our QA department has asked for some custom logic to save them some time that SOAPUI does not include.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Well, the more research I do, the more it seems like your solution is the best. Do you know if this is strictly available on an anual subscription basis? $350 per user is not bad but when you go to management and tell them to need 30 licenses at $350 per license per year (yes, I know there is volume licensing) it can get hairy.

Is it the case that you can continue using the product after the first year is up but, you just don't get support?

Comment: I believe it's support, upgrades tutorials etc. The PDF of the license agreement is on their website: http://www.eviware.com/images/stories/pdf/soapui_pro_license_agreeement.pdf. Please accept my answer if you think it is the best solution. Thanks!